# error: member reference base type 'struct configuration (char *)' is not a structure or union

Tags: c

I've looked at the other posts about this error but I cannot resolve mine somehow. Could someone please help me with this one:

This is the Header File:

```c
struct configuration{
    char *hostName;
    char *portNumber;
    char *gamekindname;
};

struct configuration getconfiguration(char* configName);
```

I defined the function in the .c File of the Header File and try to use the function in the main File to get Info from the struct:

```
getconfiguration(configName);
    // Connect to server
  const char *hostName = getconfiguration.hostName;
  const char *portNumber = getconfiguration.portNumber;
```

But I get this Error:

```
member reference base type 'struct configuration (char *)' is not a structure or union

 const char *portNumber = getconfiguration.portNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is right: `getconfiguration` is not a struct, it is a function.
You must store the result of your function call in some variable for later use:

```c
struct configuration config = getconfiguration(configName);
// Connect to server
const char *hostName = config.hostName;
const char *portNumber = config.portNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Structures in C cannot have a constructor but Structures in C++ can have Constructor creation.
2. In C++, you can create a constructor and initialize the members, like you mentioned.
3. In C, `getconfiguration` is a function which takes `char*` as an argument, and return a value of type `struct configuration`.  So using function name to access structure elements will throw you the error (`not a structure or union` error).

To solve this, see Gerhandh answer.